# I want to extract the url from the <a @href= '#' onclick="redirectpage(2);return false" >...</a>

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm using scrapy and passing SplashRequest, I want to extract the url from the @href as usual, but when I inspect the href to get the actual url, it is not assigned the url I'm looking for, but instead I see '#', then when I hover the mouse on that '#' I can see the url I'm looking for.

How can I get that url then follow it using SplashRequest ?

the HTML code is shown below:-

```
<a @href= '#' onclick="redirectpage(2);return false" >Page 120</a>
```

When I hover the mouse on @href I see the url I'm looking for as shown below :=

```
https://example.com/page/120
```

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

To get href/url attribute :

`//div[@class='---']/a/@href`

I believe this is efficient for any page

Comment: When I use the x-path I get the '#' instead of the url

Comment: This is the xpath I already tried shown below, but the debuger returns '#' as an output:-
```last_page_url = response.xpath("(//span[@class='showpageNum']/a)[last()-1]/@text()").extract_first()```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the URL, you should use some of the dynamic data fetching methods, 
Click the particular URL and view the Url in response.

If the content not available in the page source, then its loading dynamically via some scripts. 
we should handle things that way.